# Adding 'AddThis' sharing functionality to a Drupal Commerce Checkout page

Tags: commerce

How can you add the 'AddThis' sharing buttons to a Drupal Commerce checkout page?

I tried adding an AddThis field to the product content type as I do for the other content types to wish I want to add this module but that doesn't seem to add it to all the pages in the Drupal Commerce checkout process.

If anyone knows how to do that that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: If you want it to be on the checkout, you probably want to add the field to the commerce_order entity, not the product. Store > settings > order settings > manage fields. Those fields are more likely to show on the checkout pages.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...I had some trouble with this method so I just made sure the default AddThis block was also loading on other pages such as checkout/*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you discovered in your comment, the recommended approach would be to have the AddThis block show up on the `checkout/*` pages. The question is: what are you sharing, exactly?

If you're wanting to include the sharing process as part of checkout, a new, custom pane would be the best place for this.

Comment: To help my fellow colleague, you may want to look at my step-by-step that I posted years ago on drupalcommerce.org: https://drupalcommerce.org/questions/9541/how-do-i-give-customer-option-share-their-purchase-facebook-receipt-page